# How to get the text from an image in memory with C#

Tags: c#, image, text, tesseract

I try to create a simple application that read the text form an area in the screen.
I manage to do it without problem with Tesseract and Ocr but only from a file.

Here is my code :

```
 using (var bm = new Bitmap(680, 280))
            {
                using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
                {
                    gr.CopyFromScreen(-1355, 430, 0, 0, bm.Size);
                    bm.Save(@"D:\test2.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    // The image is saved in a file

                    // If required, the image can be converted to bitmap
                    Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height, gr);


                    // Get the text now
                    var Ocr = new IronTesseract
                    {
                        Language = OcrLanguage.French
                    };

                    using (var Input = new OcrInput())
                    {
                        Input.AddImage(@"D:\test2.png");

                        OcrResult Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
                        MessageBox.Show(Result.Text);
                    }

                }

            }
```

It works well but I want to do it without saving the image.

I can't find any way to do something like that

```
 using (var Input = new OcrInput())
                    {
                        Input.AddImage(myBitmap);

                        OcrResult Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
                        MessageBox.Show(Result.Text);
                    }
```

I only find how to read a text from an image **file**.

How can I do it without a file, just using the bitmap variable?

Comment: You are totaly right about mybitmap. But how can I read the text without saving the image in a file before?

Comment: Exactly which Tesseract library are you using? There are multiple Tesseract wrapper libraries for C#/.NET. (I deleted my earlier comments, I didn't understand your problem at first, sorry).

Comment: try `Input.AddImage(myBitmap);`, or any other bitmap :)

Comment: @GeorgeKarlinzer "Enable to convert System.Drawing.Bitmap" to "SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image"

Comment: @Agfasion So there's your answer then: apparently they need a `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image` and not a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

Comment: Looks like your using a commercial library called Iron Ocr to read the text from the image. You can delete the image file after reading rxt from it if you don't want it to remain on your computer

Comment: It seems this library supports a bunch of different ways to add an image including stream and byte array https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/object-reference/api/IronOcr.OcrInput.html#methods